# How to specify schema when making an URI from class.getResource("/")?

Tags: java, path, uri, nio

I was trying to set up a static utility class to provide the Paths to relative to my class.

```
public class FolderUtil {

    private static URI baseUri;
    public FolderUtil() throws URISyntaxException {
         baseUri =  FolderUtil.class.getResource("/").toURI();
    };

    public static Path getBasePath(){
        return Paths.get(baseUri).toAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

Which I thought would be valid. However when I run a JUnit test over the `getBasePath()` function, it throws a NPE!

Inspecting the Paths class I see this (code snippet not complete)

```
public static Path get(URI uri) {
        String scheme =  uri.getScheme();
        if (scheme == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing scheme");
```

Whereas the URI class says this:

```
public final class URI
    implements Comparable<URI>, Serializable
{

    // Note: Comments containing the word "ASSERT" indicate places where a
    // throw of an InternalError should be replaced by an appropriate assertion
    // statement once asserts are enabled in the build.

    static final long serialVersionUID = -6052424284110960213L;


    // -- Properties and components of this instance --

    // Components of all URIs: [<scheme>:]<scheme-specific-part>[#<fragment>]
    private transient String scheme;            // null ==> relative URI
```

Now all I can think of is that Paths must be absolute, but that doesn't make sense. Why do Paths need a Schema?

How can I specify a schema? I've tried:

```
 baseUri =  URI.create("file:").resolve(FolderUtil.class.getResource("/").toURI());
```

But it's still throwing a NPE on the schema part.

Comment: do you want to get something like `System.getProperty("user.dir");`?

Comment: @RomanVottner will that give me a valid path?

Comment: Of course, in exact it returns the base-directory of your application (= the directory where you invoked your application from). [Here you can learn more](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/misc-system/environment-variables.shtml). On your origin problem: does your path contain any blanks? for a valid URL blanks should be url-encoded with %20 f.e. `C:\Users\firstName lastName\Documents` should be something like `file:/C:/Users/firstName%20lastName/Documents`

Comment: If you solved your problem, consider posting it as an answer and accepting it so future readers may benefit.